# Adjust diacritic position in emph mode

Tags: typography, accents, characters, rendering, extended-characters

I use the the additionnal letters *ḧ*, *ĥ*, and *ḋ*. With the CMU font in emph mode.

So, with the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{CMU Serif}

\begin{document}

\emph{ḧ ĥ ḋ}

\end{document}
```

I get this rendering:

[image]

But the diacritics seems a little bit   unbalanced, especially when it is followed by other characters with the same diacritic, as you can see bellow:

[image]

So, the goal is to horizontally move the diacritics to adjust it according to the following table:

[image]

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Fix the font. No other way.

Comment: @egreg, I think so, finally. But how can I close this topic correctly?

Comment: would an answer about metafont be off-topic on this SE site?

Comment: I don’t think so. Metafont still related to LaTeX.

Comment: Personally I’d disagree with a such font since in the roman (not slanted nor italic form) variant the diacritic is centered at this place too, this would be inconsistent, and already having standard typography saying that diacritic should be centered on the character rather than on the bar or highest point or arbitrary point of the character is simpler to implement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The position of the diacritics can be adjusted using `stackinset` from the `stackengine` package. The idea is to define a separate macro for every combination of letter and diacritic. This defeats the purpose of using unicode, but the result is as required.

The arguments of `\stackinset` are horizontal align of the inserted symbol relative to the base symbol (left, center, right), horizontal offset (positive or negative), vertical align, vertical offset, inserted symbol (called inset), base symbol (called anchor).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{stackengine}

\setmainfont{CMU Serif}

\begin{document}
\emph{ḧ ĥ ḋ} (default)

\def\huml{\stackinset{c}{-1pt}{t}{-2pt}{\"{}}{h}}
\def\hcar{\stackinset{c}{-1pt}{t}{-2.5pt}{\^{}}{h}}
\def\ddot{\stackinset{c}{2.5pt}{t}{-3.5pt}{$\cdot$}{d}}

\vspace{2mm}

\emph{\huml\ \hcar\ \ddot} (with \texttt{\textbackslash stackinset})

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]