# \d{} adjust height

Tags: fonts, symbols, greek

I need to put a single dot below some letters as diacritical signs. That's what I found `\d{<text>}` for. Though, the dot is not placed at the exact same height/depth below every letter (indeed it's Greek letters). Just try the following MWE.

I've already found some kind of solution for my problem (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/437174/164672).

Though, this is not very comfortable. So my question is: Is there an easier way to adjust the height/depth of these dots below the greek letters? (Perhaps defining a new length that can be changed later...)

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek, english]{babel}
  \newcommand{\greek}[1]{\begin{otherlanguage*}{greek}#1\end{otherlanguage*}}
\begin{document}
  \d{\greek{a}} \d{\greek{b}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you check [stackengine](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/stackengine/stackengine.pdf) package?

Answer (score 1):

Following the response that you linked to, if you want to be able to change the gap between the diacritical marks and the letter, you can use [stackengine package](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/stackengine/stackengine.pdf). Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek, english]{babel}
\usepackage{stackengine}
  \newcommand{\greek}[1]{\begin{otherlanguage*}{greek}#1\end{otherlanguage*}}
\begin{document}

\def\alphael{\stackinset{c}{0pt}{b}{-7.5pt}{.}{\greek{a}}}
\def\betael{\stackinset{c}{0pt}{b}{-5pt}{.}{\greek{b}}}
\def\deltael{\stackinset{c}{0pt}{b}{-7.5pt}{.}{\greek{d}}}
\def\gammael{\stackinset{c}{0pt}{b}{-5pt}{.}{\greek{g}}}

\alphael \betael \deltael \gammael

\end{document}
```

Which yields the following output:

[image]

Your original MWE produces the following:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. How did you find these values (-7.5pt and -5 pt)?
If I use the template that my publisher gave me, your solutions does not work anymore. The dots are not typeset at the same height/depth. I guess this is due to a different font, that is used in the template. Isn't there a sfaer way to really make sure that the dots are all at the same level --- indepent on what font is used? Maybe something that uses the current baseline...

Comment: @rsa-krypto Well, as the output shows, in terms of usefulness, this answer solves your problem but still needs a few setups based on your template and your font. Do you need to add diacritical signs in this way to a large set of letters?

Comment: In total it's 95 letters. Some of them contain diacritics above.